# deploying OSGi project as Webstart using command line tools

Tags: command-line, ant, build-automation, osgi, java-web-start

How do I create a modular OSGi project that can be distributed with Java Webstart, using command line tools?

I've found [instructions to export a set of OSGi plugins from eclipse](http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/webstarting-equinox-osgi-apps). But instructions for doing so without the help of eclipse are hard to find. I would like to do this using ant build scripts and / or other command line tools.

Here is what I've got so far. Using ant, all the plug-in bundles are copied to a directory and signed. After that, I've created a jnlp file named wrapper.jnlp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp codebase="http://localhost/webstart" href="wrapper.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>My app</title>
        <vendor>Me</vendor>
        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.5+" java-vm-args="-Xmx512M"/>
        <jar href="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.jar"/>
        <extension name="Wrapper feature" href="myprogram.jnlp"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.WebStartMain"/>
    <security>
         <all-permissions/>
    </security>
</jnlp>
```

I've created a second jnlp file named myprogram.jnlp.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp codebase="http://localhost/webstart" href="myprogram.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>My app</title>
        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
    <resources>
         <j2se version="1.5+" java-vm-args="-Xmx512M"/>
         <jar href="myapp.jar"/>
         <jar href="derby.jar"/>
         <jar href="commons-math-2.0.jar"/>
             ...omitting a dozen more jar files...
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="myprogram.Main"/>
    <security>
         <all-permissions/>
    </security>
</jnlp>
```

When I deploy and try to start it (from the command line: `javaws http://localhost/webstart/wrapper.jnlp`), the jar files of the application appear to be downloaded. Then I get the following error in a log file:

```
!SESSION Wed Jun 29 13:43:52 CEST 2011 -----------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2011-06-29 13:43:52.448
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.WebStartMain.basicRun(WebStartMain.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.WebStartMain.main(WebStartMain.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:590)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:887)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Where should I look next?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  I solved it by specifying the following in my wrapper jnlp:

```
    <resources>
        <!-- Reference to the launcher jar. The version segment must be updated to the version being used-->
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar" />
        <!-- Reference to the osgi jar. The version segment must be updated to the version being used-->
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.0.v20110613.jar" />

        ...

    </resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might want to switch gears and create a P2 repository with your code and all dependencies, then have a bare-bones p2-installer pull the dependencies from there (bypassing WebStart) and start your application.

Comment: Or expanding on the ant build, use Ivy with a repository as an OBR (OSGi Bundle Repository e.g. http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-osgi-bundle-repository.html). Assume you've already seen posts like http://www.toedter.com/blog/?p=45

Comment: earcam, the blog you link has identical contents to my first link.

Comment: Hi amarillion, looks like your problem may have been solved with some help from Richard S. Hall on the felix mailing list.  Hope it's all working now/soon.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this http://www.jbundle.org/osgi-webstart/  "Use this servlet to deploy your OSGi apps to a web client."

Though it's a maven plugin from the documentation it looks like you can run it *without* a maven project.

Comment: I'm trying jbundle, but there I run into entirely different problems. For some reason, it can't resolve certain dependencies that work fine within the eclipse environment. For example, if I do this from the felix shell: `repos add http://www.bigcat.unimaas.nl/~martina/repository/repository.xml
deploy 'org.pathvisio.desktop'`, I get a long list of dependency problems.

Answer (score 0):

According to the sources, your problem is caused by failing to find `org.eclipse.osgi` bundle on the classpath. Make sure that the bundle is referenced properly and that it has correct manifest.